# How to Run 2 Jquery Function on One Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Working on jQuery Code, There are 2 Functions in that. 1st Open a Column and 2 open further tab. I Just want When 1st function `click` event is called. Then second tab content will automatically opened. Here is the code.

```js
jQuery(".block2-row, .block3").hide();
jQuery(".column").click(function() {
    jQuery(".column.active").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('tab1')) {
        jQuery(".block2-row").fadeIn(1200);
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: jQuery(".block2-row").offset().top + jQuery(".block2-row").height() + 10 - jQuery(window).height()
            }, 500);
        }, 150);
    } else {
        jQuery(".block2-row, .block3").hide();
    }
});
jQuery(".block2-row > div").click(function() {
    jQuery(".block2-row > div.active").removeClass("active");
    jQuery(this).addClass("active");
    var i = jQuery(".block2-row > div").index(this) + 1;
    jQuery(".block3").hide();
    jQuery(".block3.acc" + i).fadeIn(1200);
    var block = jQuery(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: block.offset().top - 10
        }, 500);
    }, 150);
});
jQuery(".wpb_accordion").on("accordionactivate", function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.newHeader.length) {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: jQuery(ui.newHeader).offset().top - 20
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep logic of both clicks in two different functions like and call respective function on click event

```
function fn1(){}
function fn2(){}

jQuery(".block2-row > div").click(
   fn1();
   fn2();
);
```